# Next.js' own developer guide to getting the product running doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: next.js

The [Next.js developer guide](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/32f11c34e8d342d8ab7993fcde2a6c5e7033387b/contributing/core/developing.md) does not work on an M2 Mac.

`pnpm dev` fails to start turbo, and then fails with

> Failed:    bench-nested-deps#dev, bench-nested-deps-app-router#dev

I'm the most common dev use case. Where am I going wrong?

1. I followed the instructions exactly.
2. I've deleted the entire repo and rebuilt. Same error.
3. I've run turbo outside of Next.js. Same error. <=== Misleading. See answer.
4. `next info` gets a command not found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, running turbo outside Next.js *did* work, but I made the mistake of going back to the Next.js directory and trying to run another `pnpm dev`, which failed because `pnpm dev` was already running.

In another node project besides Next.js, `pnpm dev` will work. Also, in that project repo, run `pnpm install -g next`. Next will be installed globally, and the `next info` command will work.